# Do not create sessions for unauthenticated users

Tags: express, redis, express-session

I am using `express-session` for creating sessions and `connect-redis` for storing them in a backing store. The `express-session` package creates a session for unauthenticated users also. This unnecessarily populates my backing store and wastes space. How can I avoid this behavior? I would only want to create a session for authenticated users like if someone logs in.

Comment: With express-session, that's a bit hard to do.  The challenge is that you would typically use the session to tell if a user was logged in or not.  And, if you don't call the express-session middleware, you won't have the session object in order to tell if the user is logged in or not.  But, calling the express session middleware also creates a new session if one isn't already there.  So, you'd have to somehow separate the loading of an existing session from the creating a new one.  You'll have to investigate the express-session code to see if it can do that.

Comment: Did you look into the saveUninitialized option? see https://github.com/expressjs/session#saveuninitialized

Comment: what about submitting this answer @CapiEtheriel ?